# how to get only user's photo list by Listview django

Tags: django, listview, get, photo

All.

I want to use Listview to show only user's photo list not other user's photo list. but it doesn't work. user can get other user's photo.

this is views.py

```
class PhotoListView(ListView):
model = Photo

def get(self, *args, **kwargs):

    #if user connect to other user's page, go to the user's page.
    if kwargs['username'] != self.request.user.username:
         return redirect('index')

    #to get only user's photo list.
    username = self.request.user.username
    return super(PhotoListView, self).get(username=username, *args, **kwargs)
```

this is model.py

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    image_file = ProcessedImageField(upload_to='%Y/%m/%d/orig', format='JPEG', options={'quality': 100})
    source = TaggableManager(through=Taggedsource, related_name='source')
    subject = TaggableManager(through=Taggedsubject, related_name='subject')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    comments = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    posted_on = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should edit the `get_queryset` method:

```
class PhotoListView(ListView):
    model = Photo

    def get_queryset(self):
        photos = super().get_queryset()
        username = self.request.user.username
        photos = photos.objects.filter(user=username)
        return photos

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):

        #if user connect to other user's page, go to the user's page.
        if kwargs['username'] != self.request.user.username:
            return redirect('index')
```

Answer (score 1):

In views.py

```
class PhotoListView(ListView):
model = Photo

def get(self, *args, **kwargs):

    #if user connect to other user's page, go to the user's page.
    if kwargs['username'] != self.request.user.username:
        return redirect('index')

    #to get only user's photo list.
    username = self.request.user.username
    photos = Photo.objects.filter(user=username)
    return photos
```

`Photo.objects.filter(user=username)` will get only photos of that user.